# Collide and slide a sphere against complex geometry

Tags: collision-detection, game-physics, typescript

I could use some help figuring out collision response. I'm trying to implement what is presented [in this paper](http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs195u/lectures/lecture6.pdf) on slides 4 to 10. Collision detection works, and the colliding entity **does** slide along the collision plane but with severely reduced speed. I'm not sure whether I'm properly projecting the leftover velocity on collision plane.

```
class CollisionPacket {
    // INPUT:
    colliderRadius: vec3;
    colliderPosition: vec3;
    colliderVelocity: vec3;

    // OUTPUT:    
    collisionFound: bool;
    collisionTime: number;  // how far can we travel before we collide?
    collisionPoint: vec3;   // point on triangle where collision ocurred
    collisionNormal: vec3;  // normal of nearest collided triangle
}

collideAndSlide(position: vec3, velocity: vec3, radius: number): vec3 {
    var packet = new CollisionPacket();

    packet.colliderRadius = radius;
    packet.colliderPosition = position;
    packet.colliderVelocity = velocity;

    packet.collisionTime = 0.0;
    packet.collisionFound = false;

    var maxIterations = 5;

    do {
        // check nearby triangles for collisions
        this.collideWorld(packet);

        var newPosition = packet.colliderPosition.copy();
        var newVelocity = packet.colliderVelocity.copy();

        if (packet.collisionFound) {
            // scale velocity vector to collide with nearest triangle
            var scaledVelocity = packet.colliderVelocity.copy().scale(packet.collisionTime);

            // move a tiny bit away from collision along collision normal
            scaledVelocity.add(packet.collisionNormal.copy().scale(0.001));

            // add scaled velocity to position
            newPosition.add(scaledVelocity);

            // and remove it from leftover velocity
            newVelocity.subtract(scaledVelocity);

            // extract part of velocity vector which is perpendicular to collision plane (CORRECT?)
            var v = packet.collisionNormal.copy().scale(vec3.dot(newVelocity, packet.collisionNormal));

            // remove that part from velocity vector
            newVelocity = vec3.difference(newVelocity, v);

            // update values for next iteration
            packet.colliderPosition = newPosition;
            packet.colliderVelocity = newVelocity;
        }
        else {
            // no collision, move as requested
            newPosition.add(packet.colliderVelocity);
        }
    } while (--maxIterations > 0 && packet.collisionFound)

    return newPosition;
}
```

I visualized both *v* and *newVelocity* after *v* has been subtracted from it and they look how they're supposed to: *v* is perpendicular to the collision plane, *newVelocity* runs parallel to it in the direction we're moving.

If I add *newVelocity* directly to *newPosition* instead of doing the recursion, like this:

```
                ...

                // remove that part from velocity vector
                newVelocity = vec3.difference(newVelocity, v);

                newPosition.add(newVelocity);
        }
        else {
                // no collision, move as requested
                newPosition.add(packet.colliderVelocity);
        }
    } while (false)
```

the entity is sliding as it should, without being slowed down, so I'm quite sure the vectors are ok.

However, *maxIterations* always runs down to zero, so there's always collisions. maybe that's slowing it down?

Would someone with a better understanding of the underlying math have a look?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Illustration of the vectors after the first iteration:

[image]

The box is colliding against the wall (invisible on this screenshot due to backface culling)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: I forgot to reset packet.collisionTime at the beginning of each iteration, this it what slowed it all down. It works as expected now. Maybe the code is helpful to someone else.